# User Process Tracking, what is this? Numerous alerts with FastCGI

Tags: vps, fastcgi, process

I have a CentOS VPS on Knownhost.com. I am using it to host one Wordpress site, that currently doesn't have any traffic (not launched yet). I was getting these process tracking emails (7 different procs) constantly after Knownhost installed FastCGI.

The problem is i'm not sure *what* this means... I could find info on google about how to stop it, but not what it means.

Here is an example of message:

```
Time:         Thu Apr 21 16:25:31 2011 -0400
Account:      myuser
Resource:     Process Time
Exceeded:     1855 > 1800 (seconds)
Executable:   /usr/bin/php
Command Line: /usr/bin/php
PID:          25627
Killed:       No
```

The confusing part is that the site is not launched and there is 0 traffic. I also could not find the processes in WHM/Cpanel.

From Knownhost:

> We have added the user "myuser" to
>   the /etc/csf/csf.pignore file to
>   prevent such fake alerts in future.
>
> Please note that Fcgi method is only
>   recommended for advanced
>   administrators who understand how to
>   tune the performance of mod_fcgid. So
>   it is better to switch from fcgi to
>   suphp.
>
> Let us know if you need further
>   assistance.

Would you guys concur with this? I am a linux noob, but I would like to think I could research enough to tune FastCGI (though honestly, I know nothing about it)

Also if it helps, this is from WHM...

Server load   0.00 (36 CPUs)
  Memory Used   13.50% (106188 of 786432)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, to me it seems like the fastcgi process is running under the user and it is a process that just runs in the background indefinitely. So either set apache fastcgi config to kill worker after it after it is X old.. Or disable the monitor.